# Camel type converter fails: InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type

Tags: osgi, apache-camel

The application is based on OSGI.
I have a custom annotated converter:

```
package com.domain.bundle1.web.camel.converters;

import ...;

@Converter
public class FooTransferObjectConverter {
    public FooTransferObjectConverter() {
    }

    @Converter
    public static FooTransferObject toFooTransferObject(Foo foo, Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // some magic
        return fooTransferObject;
    }
}
```

Also i declared package where it plased in TypeConverter file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3QQH.png

which contains:

```
com.domain.bundle1.web.camel.converters
```

And camel-context file contains next code:

```
<log loggingLevel="INFO" message="Converting to FooTransferObject" />
<convertBodyTo type="com.domain.bundle2.model.FooTransferObject" />
<log loggingLevel="INFO" message="Converted!" />
```

Before converting, body of message is a Foo object.

But when process reaches converting, then throws an exception:

```
Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-EPUALVIW0567-55536-1401106375216-26-5 on ExchangeId: ID-EPUALVIW0567-55536-1401106375216-26-6).    
Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: com.domain.bundle2.model.FooTransferObject but has value: Foo{97, Wall, null, null} of type: com.domain.bundle3.model.Foo on: Message: Foo{97, Wall, null, null}. 
Caused by: Error during type conversion from type: com.domain.bundle3.model.Foo to the required type: com.domain.bundle2.model.FooTransferObject with value Foo{97, Wall, null, null} due 6 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions. Exchange[Message: Foo{97, Wall, null, null}]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException - Error during type conversion from type: Foo{97, Wall, null, null} to the required type: com.domain.bundle2.model.FooTransferObjec with value....
```

then exception cached by custom handler,
and then I found this:

```
    Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: freebaseball SpeedKick  -> fr????f????tb??ll Sp????dK??ck  -> free
football SpeedKick ]
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:311)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)[:1.7.0_40]
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
        at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.FallbackTypeConverter.marshall(FallbackTypeConverter.java:238)
        at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.FallbackTypeConverter.convertTo(FallbackTypeConverter.java:95)
        ... 163 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: freebaseball SpeedKick  -> fr????f????tb??ll Sp????dK??c
k  -> freebaseball SpeedKick
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:237)[:1.7.0_40]
```

How do You think what's a problem? How can I see loaded converters in TypeConverterRegistry?

Comment: can you post more of the stacktrace of the error, as it says something about illegal annotation exception which is weird.

Comment: I don't understand, why camel try to serialize to XML the Foo object when process reaches converting?

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved my problem. FallbackTypeConverter started work, because camel didn't load my custom regular type converter. 
I checked the map of converters in TypeConverterRegister in debug mode, and didn't find my FooTransferObjectConverter.

The problem was in file `TypeConverter`. I just added name of converter class to path and after that it loaded to registry.

```
com.domain.bundle1.web.camel.converters.FooTransferObjectConverter
```

Camel version in application - 2.11.1. In [camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html) written next:

> In Camel 2.8 we improved the type converter loader to support
>   specifying the FQN class name of the converter classes. This has the
>   advantage of avoiding having to scan packages for @Converter classes.
>   Instead it loads the @Converter class directly. This is a highly
>   recommend approach to use going forward.

But i tryed run the [application from chapter 3 (from 'Camel in action' book) with custom converter](https://code.google.com/p/camelinaction/downloads/detail?name=camelinaction-source-2111.zip&can=2&q=). And file `TypeConverter` contained only from package path.